# ESP32 serial monitor not working properly

Tags: esp32, stepper

I want to connect an ESP32 module to a TMC2209 driver. I'm new in this, so I want to try easy stuff first. I'm using the TMC2209 library https://github.com/janelia-arduino/TMC2209/tree/main

I'm using one of their examples to test the baud rates, but I can't see a thing in the serial monitor in VScode with PlatformIO.

This is the PlatformIO configuration and code that I'm using:

```
[env:nodemcu-32s]
platform = espressif32
board = nodemcu-32s
framework = arduino
lib_deps = janelia-arduino/TMC2209@^9.0.6
monitor_speed = 115200
```

--

```c++
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <TMC2209.h>

// This example will not work on Arduino boards without HardwareSerial ports,
// such as the Uno, Nano, and Mini.
//
// See this reference for more details:
// https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/

HardwareSerial & serial_stream = Serial1;

const long SERIAL_BAUD_RATE = 115200;
const long SERIAL1_BAUD_RATE_COUNT = 10;
const long SERIAL1_BAUD_RATES[SERIAL1_BAUD_RATE_COUNT] =
{
  500000,
  250000,
  115200,
  57600,
  38400,
  31250,
  28800,
  19200,
  14400,
  9600
};
const uint8_t SUCCESSIVE_OPERATION_COUNT = 3;
const int DELAY = 2000;

// Instantiate TMC2209
TMC2209 stepper_driver;
uint8_t serial1_baud_rate_index = 0;

const int RX_PIN = 3;
const int TX_PIN = 1;


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(SERIAL_BAUD_RATE);
}

void loop()
{
  long serial1_baud_rate = SERIAL1_BAUD_RATES[serial1_baud_rate_index++];
  //stepper_driver.setup(serial_stream, SERIAL_BAUD_RATE, TMC2209::SERIAL_ADDRESS_0, RX_PIN, TX_PIN);
  //stepper_driver.setup(serial_stream,serial1_baud_rate);
  stepper_driver.setup(serial_stream, serial1_baud_rate, TMC2209::SERIAL_ADDRESS_1, RX_PIN, TX_PIN);
  if (serial1_baud_rate_index == SERIAL1_BAUD_RATE_COUNT)
  {
    serial1_baud_rate_index = 0;
  }

  bool test_further = false;

  Serial.println("*************************");
  Serial.print("serial1_baud_rate = ");
  Serial.println(serial1_baud_rate);

  if (stepper_driver.isSetupAndCommunicating())
  {
    Serial.println("Stepper driver setup and communicating!");
    test_further = true;
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Stepper driver not setup and communicating!");
  }

  if (test_further)
  {
    uint32_t microstep_sum = 0;
    for (uint8_t i=0; i<SUCCESSIVE_OPERATION_COUNT; ++i)
    {
      microstep_sum += stepper_driver.getMicrostepsPerStep();
    }
    if (microstep_sum > 0)
    {
      Serial.println("Successive read test passed!");
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("Successive read test failed!");
    }
    uint8_t itc_begin = stepper_driver.getInterfaceTransmissionCounter();
    for (uint8_t i=0; i<SUCCESSIVE_OPERATION_COUNT; ++i)
    {
      stepper_driver.disable();
    }
    uint8_t itc_end = stepper_driver.getInterfaceTransmissionCounter();
    if (itc_begin != itc_end)
    {
      Serial.println("Successive write test passed!");
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("Successive write test failed!");
    }
  }

  Serial.println("*************************");
  Serial.println();
  delay(DELAY);
}
```

and this is what I see in the Serial Monitor
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your code is using 1 and 3 as the TX and RX pins for `Serial1`. These pins are already used as TX and RX for `Serial` and are wired to the board's USB/UART chip. You're seeing garbage because you're sending garbage. Choose a different pair of pins that aren't already in use and change your wiring and software to use that pair of pins.

An easy way to debug this is to write a simple program that does nothing but output `Hello World` to `Serial` - eliminate everything else from your program and disconnect anything you have from pins 1 and 3. That will work correctly. When you see that work correctly it will be clear that the fault lies in the rest of your program.

Edit:

You can configure a second hardware serial port like this:

```
Serial1.begin(SERIAL1_BAUD_RATE_COUNT, SERIAL_8N1, RX_PIN, TX_PIN);
```

You would also need to change the `#define` lines to use the correct new pin numbers for `RX_PIN` and `TX_PIN`.

The rest of your code is already set up to use `Serial1`.

Comment: Many thanks. I was using pin 1 and 3 because on the diagram of the ESP32 module are the TX and RX pins. I've changed the code to use pin 2 and 4 and it worked. It's now showing right in the serial monitor. It means that I cannot use the boards pin 1 and 3 at all? Will pins 2 and 4 work properly to communicate via UART to the TMC2209?
This is the board I'm using https://www.az-delivery.de/en/products/esp32-developmentboard

Comment: GPIO1 and GPIO3 are permanently wired to the USB/UART adapter on the board you're using. And internally they're routed to UART0 (`Serial`). So they're already in use. You can only use them for other things if you don't care about losing the ability to use serial over USB. Also the RX pin is unlikely to be usable for anything else unless you sever the trace connecting it to the USB/UART chip. So basically unless you really know what you're doing, no, you can't use them for anything else. GPIO2 is okay to use as an output but if it has a HIGH signal on it you won't be able to flash the board.

Comment: My idea is to use the TMC2209 to drive a stepper motor. I believe I need the RX pin to know when the motor hits an end stop, but please correct me if I'm wrong. The TMC2209 has sensorless homing.

Comment: You have to *not* use the RX pin as it's already in use by the USB/UART chip. You need to use the input to a different UART, UART1. I updated the answer to explain how to set up the second hardware UART, `Serial1.`